# Read/write date values with Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I have some questions about read/write date values with apache pdfbox.

1. How can I identify that a field is a date field (expect a date value) ?
2. Is it possible to read the format (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy) format of a pdf field? I found no way to do this. I see the format in the COSDictionary of the field but it is part of a javascript call.
3. How can I set the value of a date field correctly?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, plain AcroForm PDF syntax does not know dedicated date field, merely text fields. What makes such text fields dedicated date fields with a specified date format in Adobe Acrobat Reader, is JavaScript associated with text field events. To determine the "type" of the text field, therefore, you need to analyze the JavaScript associated with the field (if any is). As far as I know PDFBox does not include methods that already do that analysis for you, so you have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Concerning *"how to set the value of a date field **correctly**"*... let's assume by *"correctly"* you mean *in a format the associated JavaScript would have forced the input to conform to in a PDF viewer with activated JavaScript support* because as far as the pure PDF is concerned, other formats are not less correct than the JavaScript enforced one. And again there is no specific support for this in PDFBox, you have to parse the associated JavaScript, extract the format information, format the data, and set the formatted data as field value.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265), the field format is defined by JavaScript code. The way I have been able to get the format associated to it is the following:

```
String js = Optional.ofNullable(acroForm.getField(fieldName)).map(PDField::getCOSObject)
        // Additional-actions dictionary. Defining the actions to be taken in response to various trigger events.
        .map(d -> (COSDictionary) d.getDictionaryObject(COSName.AA))
        // F dictionary. A JavaScript action to be performed before the field is formatted to display its current value.
        .map(d -> (COSDictionary) d.getDictionaryObject(COSName.F))
        // JS string. A string or stream containing the JavaScript script to be executed.
        .map(d -> d.getString(COSName.JS))
        .orElse(null);
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("AFDate_FormatEx\\s*\\(([^)]*)\\)").matcher(js);
m.find();
String dateFormat = m.group(1);
```

It then needs to be parsed though, as PDF date formats are not equal to Java date formats.